# An alternative to create a layout?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, react-bootstrap

I want to create a layout containing the header and footer, with in middle every other component.

It will look something like this:

```
<Layout>

<Component1/>
<Component2/>
...
</Layout>
```

Technically I already achieved the desired outcome by using [semantic ui react's Container](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/container/) and my code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Header from './Head';

export default props => {
    return (
      <Container style={{width:'100%'}}>
        <Header/>
        <div style={{marginTop: '1%'}}>
        {props.children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    );
  };
```

I would like to achieve the same result, but without using the Container offered by semantic-ui-react. 
I tried in fact to remove `<Container>` but I am getting this error:

> Line 9:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an
>   enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?

If I remove completely the `<div>` tag I am getting another error:

> Unexpected token, expected ","

I am not 100% sure but I understood that I should be using a class which expands the react component. I tried this which also failed:

```
class props extends React.Component {
  render(){  
  return (
        <Header/>
        {props.children}
        <Footer />
    );
  }
  };

  export default props;
```

Comment: Instead of `<Container>... </Container>` you can simply use a react fragment -  `<React.fragment>...</React.fragment>` or `<>....</>`  --> https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

Comment: Or an array of elements with different keys (if that is still supported)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the <React.fragment>. I found out that I can also use a simple <div> which I haven't tried, assuming it was a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `<Container/>`, but you will still need a parent component to wrap `<Header/>`, `<Footer/>`, and your content `div`, if you wish to keep the same markup.  If, for semantic reasons, you don't want to use a `div`, use `<React.Fragment/>` as **zfrisch** mentioned

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Header from './Head';

    export default props => {
        return (
          <div style={{width:'100%'}}> // OR <React.Fragment/>
            <Header/>
            <div style={{marginTop: '1%'}}>
            {props.children}
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
      };
```